# I am trying to get the Digest SHA value from artifactory and wondering how I can get that

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli

In Artifactory when you search for the package, it has the following column:

- Version
- Repositories
- Digest
- Modified
- Downloads
- Xray Status

I am trying to find how I can retrieve the DIGEST SHA value using the cli.  I have tried multiple commands and having no luck.  I have researched and tried multiple approaches and below is the command I came close to but it does not have the same value.

This is the command I have tried and the sha value does not match the DIGEST value in artifactory.

`curl -s -u username:password  -o abc.tar https://artifactory.com/artifactory/api/storage/x-a12345-docker-core-local/dev/<repo>/<tag> && shasum -a 256 abc.tar`

I also tried this command, but I am getting a blank output:

`curl -s -u username:password -H "Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json" "https://artifactory.com/artifactory/api/storage/x-a12345-docker-core-local/dev/<repo>@<tag> | jq -r '.config.digest'`

I need to get the DIGEST SHA value and wondering anyone can assist.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 options; 1 via REST API and another via AQL query (which you can run either via REST API or via JFrog CLI).

1_ https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ItemProperties

```
curl http://artifactory-url/api/storage/libs-release-local/org/acme | | jq .checksums.sha1
```

https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/artifactory-how-to-retrieve-information-about-artifacts/

2_ https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Query+Language#ArtifactoryQueryLanguage-EntitiesandFields
[image: sha256-field]

```
items.find({"repo":"your-repository","path":"path/of/your/artifacts","name":"name-of-your-artifact"})
     .include("repo","path","name","sha256")
```

Comment: I feel like RestAPI method will work, however, when i try to use the curl command `curl http://artifactory-url/api/storage/libs-release-local/org/acme | | jq .checksums.sha1`  I am only getting the **Folder Info – Retrieves folder information** I am trying to see what will be the best way to get the sha value.  I need to use this in python script to pull the repo via the digest sha value.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the above description, it seems like you are looking for the modified timestamp from the Artifactory package view. The Package view shows the items processed by the [Metadata service](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Metadata+Migration+in+the+JFrog+Platform) and we should be able to query them using [Artifactory GraphQL](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/GraphQL). I am also sharing a [knowledge base article](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/artifactory-how-to-retrieve-information-about-artifacts/) that will have the syntax and an example(i.e retrieve metadata of packages in Artifactory).